# Install Lua in Linux and implement PHP Lua Extension

Tags: php, linux, lua, pecl

I installed Lua via:

```
apt-get install lua5.3 lua5.3-dev
```

Then made

```
pecl install lua
```

which gave me this error: `Please reinstall the lua distribution - lua.h should be in <lua-dir>/include/`

But I dunno where this `<lua-dir>` should be. Following instructions in this question:
[lua php extension installation via pecl fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214769/lua-php-extension-installation-via-pecl-fails)
did not help

Comment: Does `--with-lua-version=5.3` help?

Comment: yes this worked, thanks!
But know I stuck in creating a Lua variable ($lua = new Lua()). It says tha the class is not found, what have I to do?

Comment: ok found a solution

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
pecl download lua
cd lua-2.0.7
phpize
./configure --with-lua-version=5.3
make
cp modules/lua.so /usr/lib/php/20151012/lua.so
```

Add in php.ini:

```
extension=lua.so
```